# What is the alternate command for "kudzu" in RHEL6?

Tags: rhel6

I used "kudzu" command in RHEL5 for scanning new devices connected to the server. But i am getting "command not found" error when I try the same in RHEL6.

What is the alternative command for scanning new devices connected to the server in RHEL6.
Pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of new devices?

Comment: network cards (NIC)

Answer (score 1):

You should no longer need to run any command to detect new devices; they should be detected and configured automatically when you connect them. If you have a device that isn't, then you should investigate that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need `kudzu` in RHEL6 or its derivatives.

For configuring network adapters, I'd look at the command `system-config-network`. If you can't find the device, take a look at `less /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

All new devices should be logged in `less /var/log/dmesg` when connected. Other options include `lspci` and `lsusb`.